# Unable to parse jsonObject to post as a payload

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a json Data on test.json file which looks like

```
{
"name":"myName",
"fovoriteFood":"SHiro",
"favoriteColor": "blue",
"favoritedress": "Tilfi",
"dateOfBirth":"03/23/1921"
}
```

And I have my code looks like with debugging

````
```public static JsonPath getPostDataFromJsonFile() {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(".\\src\\test\\resources\\data\\postTest.json");
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
    logger.info("JSONObject ==: " + object); //object: size = 5
    logger.info("JSONObject ==: " + object.toString()); // {"zip":"55113","firstName":"Randy","lastName":"Lindorfer","dateOfBirth":"03\/23\/1958","uniqueId":"01052361"}
    String data = object.toString();
    logger.info("Here DATA ==: " + data);

    Response response = ServiceHelper.post(env.url, data);
    logger.info("this is data from responce  == " + response);
    logger.info("status code is " + response.getStatusCode());
    JsonPath jsonPath = response.jsonPath();
    logger.debug("response: " + jsonPath.prettyPrint());
    return jsonPath;```
````

On debugging I see the data as data: {"zip":"55113","firstName":"Randy","lastName":"Lindorfer","dateOfBirth":"03/23/1958","uniqueId":"01052361"} not sure is this is the issue but need help in figuring out.
I have spent two days in googling and tried different possible solution from stackoverflow and nothing seems to work, I really need help where my error is and what am I missing. It worth to mention that I have tried Json Simple as well as Googles gson,
This is the Exception I am getting

Exception in thread "main" io.restassured.path.json.exception.JsonPathException: Failed to parse the JSON document
Caused by: groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while reading '<', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.
at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parse(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:97)
Appreciate your help.

When I debug I am able to read the file and see the contents of the object and the size but nothing is printing out on the console and nothing is posted on my api body
where is my mistake in here, please help!!!

Comment: So what is your issue exactly? You didn't even say what the issue is.

Comment: Do you get any output if you would try printing the contents of `Reader`? Because it might be the root cause, that the `reader` has content to be read. `Assert` will fail test or throw NPE because the`reader` is null or empty.

Comment: @RR_IL, My Issue is unable to parse json, my json data is  in a file, even though am able to read and print it on my console when saving as object or String it saying Not a JSON Object: null